# Content-Length value for compressed response

Tags: http, http-compression

If I send a request to http server with header containing:

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate;
```

and the response has

```
Content-Encoding: gzip;
Content-Length:fsize;
```

Is the fsize is the compressed value or uncompressed one?

If it is compressed, is it possible to get the actual/uncompressed size?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Content-Length describes size of transmitted block; if compression enabled, it would be compressed size.

Like with any other lossless compression format - to get uncompressed size, you need to inflate (decompress) received data.